# Emacs Modus themes

Tags: org-mode, faces, themes

I would like to add a language in the `org-src-block-faces` list:

```lisp
     (defun gb/org-src-block-faces ()
         (add-to-list 'org-src-block-faces
               '("Php" modus-themes-nuanced-magenta)))
          (add-hook 'modus-themes-after-load-theme-hook
               'gb/org-src-block-faces)
          (load-theme 'modus-vivendi :no-confirm)
```

But the variable is updated only when I toggle the themes; is it possible to modify this list? and do we have to do an

> org-mode-restart

and when?

Comment: You use this theme by default? Or you'd like to apply the `org-src-block-faces` only when using a modus theme?

Comment: I use it by default, and i toggle with modus-operandi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with `modus-themes` is a bit tricky, depends on Emacs version,
if this package is built-in or downloaded from MELPA and your configuration style.
Read the [manual page](https://protesilaos.com/emacs/modus-themes).
Quoting from the manual:

> Remember that all customization options must be evaluated before loading a theme (Enable and load). If the theme is already active, it must be reloaded for changes to take effect.

So we can write:

```lisp
(setq modus-themes-org-blocks 'tinted-background)
(load-theme 'modus-vivendi)
```

Next, in your org-mode configuration (after the previous snippet) you may add the following:

```lisp
  (add-to-list 'org-src-block-faces
               '("Php" modus-themes-nuanced-magenta))
  (setq org-fontify-whole-block-delimiter-line t)
```

The last line above extend face to the whole line.
And the last step is to apply the `org-mode-restart` (outside of org-mode):

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'org-mode
  (org-mode-restart))
```

And restart the Emacs.

Comment: Ty, it works, but for sure it will be better to tell Prot to add it in the main list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are toggling the themes, but I guess you use `modus-themes-toggle`.

Then you can create a function that conditionally adds/removes the element to/from the `org-src-block-faces` list and updates font-lock in all org buffers, and add that function to the `modus-themes-after-load-theme-hook` as follows:

```lisp
(defun gb/org-src-block-faces ()
  (interactive)
  ;; conditionally add/remove element
  (setq org-src-block-faces
        (funcall (if (memq 'modus-vivendi custom-enabled-themes)
                     #'cons
                   #'delete)
                 '("php" modus-themes-nuanced-magenta)
                 org-src-block-faces))

  ;; get all org buffers
  (let ((org-buffers (seq-filter (lambda (buf)
                                   (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buf) 'org-mode))
                                 (buffer-list))))
    ;; update font-lock in all org buffers
    (dolist (b org-buffers)
      (with-current-buffer b
        (font-lock-update)))))
```

The code looks a little over-complicated to me. Maybe someone can come up with a simpler solution (e.g. does there exist a 'global' font-lock update function? Of course, to make the code simpler, we could remove the 'org' filter, and just update font-lock in all buffers).